# Azure python sdk, how to deploy a vm and it's a Azure Spot instance

Tags: python, azure-sdk-python

Azure python sdk, 
how to deploy a vm and it's a Azure Spot instance

Comment: Do you have any other concerns? If you have no other concerns, could you please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). It may help persons who have a similar issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create Azure Spot VM, please refer to the following code. For more deatils, please refer to the [doucment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-compute/azure.mgmt.compute.v2019_07_01.models.virtualmachine?view=azure-python) and the [docuemnt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/python)

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.compute.v2019_07_01 import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.compute.v2019_07_01.models import VirtualMachinePriorityTypes, VirtualMachineEvictionPolicyTypes, BillingProfile
SUBSCRIPTION_ID = 'subscription-id'
GROUP_NAME = 'myResourceGroup'
LOCATION = 'westus'
VM_NAME = 'myVM'
credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
        client_id = 'application-id',
        secret = 'authentication-key',
        tenant = 'tenant-id'
    )
compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(
    credentials,
    SUBSCRIPTION_ID
)
vm_parameters = {
        'location': LOCATION,
        'os_profile': {
            'computer_name': VM_NAME,
            'admin_username': 'azureuser',
            'admin_password': 'Azure12345678'
        },
        'hardware_profile': {
            'vm_size': 'Standard_DS1'
        },
        'storage_profile': {
            'image_reference': {
                'publisher': 'MicrosoftWindowsServer',
                'offer': 'WindowsServer',
                'sku': '2012-R2-Datacenter',
                'version': 'latest'
            }
        },
        'network_profile': {
            'network_interfaces': [{
                'id': nic.id
            }]
        },
        'priority':VirtualMachinePriorityTypes.spot, # use Azure spot intance
        'eviction_policy':VirtualMachineEvictionPolicyTypes.deallocate , #For Azure Spot virtual machines, the only supported value is 'Deallocate'
        'billing_profile': BillingProfile(max_price=float(2)) 
creation_result = compute_client.virtual_machines.create_or_update(
        GROUP_NAME, 
        VM_NAME, 
        vm_parameters
    )
print(creation_result.result())
    }
```

[image]