# I am having RDP access issues when trying to create a spot instance on azure through azure api for python

Tags: python, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-api-apps

I am trying to create a spot instance on azure from azure API through python code. The following code successfully creates the spot instance machine on Azure but when I try to connect through RDP, the credentials given in the API does not work.

```
import secrets
from datetime import datetime

from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient

from azure.mgmt.network import NetworkManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.compute.models import (
    VirtualMachine,
    HardwareProfile,
    StorageProfile,
    InstanceViewTypes,
    OSDisk,
    ManagedDiskParameters,
    DiskCreateOptionTypes,
    OSProfile,
    NetworkProfile,
    NetworkInterfaceReference,
    VirtualMachinePriorityTypes,
    VirtualMachineEvictionPolicyTypes,
    BillingProfile
)
from azure.mgmt.network.models import PublicIPAddress, IPAllocationMethod, NetworkSecurityGroup, SecurityRule
from constance import config

from instance.client_utils.ssh_client import SSHClient
from instance.models import VMInstance
from syntric_cr.settings import (
    AZURE_CLIENT_ID,
    AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    AZURE_TENANT,
    AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID,
    AZURE_CAPTURE_IMAGE,
    AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP,
    AZURE_RDP_USERNAME,
    AZURE_LOCATION, AZURE_EXISTING_NIC_NAME, AZURE_EXISTING_NSG_NAME,
)


def create_spot_instance(self):
        current_timestamp = round(datetime.timestamp(datetime.now()))

        vm_name = f"spot-{current_timestamp}"

        vm_username = AZURE_RDP_USERNAME
        vm_password = secrets.token_urlsafe(13)
        vm_location = AZURE_LOCATION
        vm_image_id = self.get_image_id(AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP, AZURE_CAPTURE_IMAGE)
        new_nic = self.creating_nic_and_ip_from_existing_vm(vm_name, vm_location)

        vm_params = VirtualMachine(
            location=vm_location,
            hardware_profile=HardwareProfile(vm_size=config.AZURE_VIRTUAL_MACHINE_SIZE),
            storage_profile=StorageProfile(
                image_reference={'id': vm_image_id},
                os_disk=OSDisk(
                    name=vm_name,
                    create_option=DiskCreateOptionTypes.from_image,
                    managed_disk=ManagedDiskParameters(storage_account_type='Standard_LRS')
                )
            ),
            os_profile=OSProfile(
                computer_name=vm_name,
                admin_username='hello',
                admin_password='hello_123'
            ),
            network_profile=NetworkProfile(
                network_interfaces=[
                    NetworkInterfaceReference(id=new_nic.id)
                ]
            ),
            priority=VirtualMachinePriorityTypes.spot,
            eviction_policy=VirtualMachineEvictionPolicyTypes.deallocate,
            billing_profile=BillingProfile(max_price=config.AZURE_MAX_SPOT_INSTANCE_BUDGET)
        )

        try:
            self.service.virtual_machines.begin_create_or_update(AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP, vm_name, vm_params)
            return VMInstance.objects.create(
                instance=vm_name, project=AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP, provider='AZURE', status=False,
                script_run_on_start=False, username=vm_username, password=vm_password)
        except Exception as ex:
            return
```

The username 'hello' and the password 'hello_123' does not work for the RDP access when the spot instance is created. I have to then manually reset the password in order to make it work

I tried the code above and copied this from the official Azure docs

Answer (score 0):

> The username 'hello' and the password 'hello_123' does not work for
> the RDP access when the spot instance is created. I have to then
> manually reset the password in order to make it work

By default hello_123  is not supported as a password due to username and password limitations while deploying Azure VM, I tried creating a Spot VM with hello_123 password and the password was not selected due to the naming conventions and a **Warning - The value must be between 12 and 123 characters long**, Refer below:-

[image]

***I tried creating a Spot VM with Python SDK by following the username and password naming conventions as mentioned in this Document:-***

**Username-** [FAQ about Windows VMs in Azure - Azure Virtual Machines | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/faq#what-are-the-username-requirements-when-creating-a-vm-)

**Password-** [FAQ about Windows VMs in Azure - Azure Virtual Machines | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/faq#what-are-the-password-requirements-when-creating-a-vm-)

**My Python code to Deploy a SpotVM:-**

```py
# from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials

from  azure.identity  import  DefaultAzureCredential

from  azure.mgmt.compute.v2019_07_01  import  ComputeManagementClient

from  azure.mgmt.compute.v2019_07_01.models  import  VirtualMachinePriorityTypes, VirtualMachineEvictionPolicyTypes, BillingProfile

SUBSCRIPTION_ID = '<subscription-id>'

GROUP_NAME = '<resource-group-name>'

LOCATION = 'Australia East'

VM_NAME = '<vm-name>'

credentials = DefaultAzureCredential()

compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(

credentials,

SUBSCRIPTION_ID

)

vm_parameters = {

'location': LOCATION,

'os_profile': {

'computer_name': VM_NAME,

'admin_username': '<username-accroding-to-naming-convention>',

'admin_password': '<password-according-to-naming-convention>'

},

'hardware_profile': {

'vm_size': 'Standard_D2s_v3'

},

'storage_profile': {

'image_reference': {

'publisher': 'MicrosoftWindowsServer',

'offer': 'WindowsServer',

'sku': '2019-Datacenter',

'version': 'latest'

}

},

'network_profile': {

'network_interfaces': [{

'id': "nic-id"

}]

},

'priority': VirtualMachinePriorityTypes.spot, # use Azure spot intance

'eviction_policy': VirtualMachineEvictionPolicyTypes.deallocate, # For Azure Spot virtual machines, the only supported value is 'Deallocate'

'billing_profile': BillingProfile(max_price=float(2))

}

  
  

creation_result = compute_client.virtual_machines.begin_create_or_update(

GROUP_NAME,

VM_NAME,

vm_parameters

)

print(creation_result.result())
```

**Output:-**

[image]

**VM got created on Portal** and **I attached NSG and Public IP to the VM** and **tried to RDP** into it **with the credentials** given in the code and it was **successful**, Refer below:-

[image]

**RDP:-**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Reference:-**

[Azure python sdk, how to deploy a vm and it's a Azure Spot instance - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60275717/azure-python-sdk-how-to-deploy-a-vm-and-its-a-azure-spot-instance) By Jim Xu

Comment: Thank you for giving answer.I have an azure machine which have installed many softwares like blender,Pycharm and so on.So i capture that vm image and try to create spot instance from this image.Spot instance is created but when i use same credentails for accessing VM.it shows me that account does not work.This works when i don't create an vm from my generated image.Please have a look?

Comment: Here the issue is not related to the images, but the RDP protocol used while deploying VM in Azure, And for successful, RDP you need to pass username and password according to the requirements mentioned in the VM FAQ Check the image here even when I select centos image - https://i.imgur.com/QyfEvSf.png the administrator account   option is different and requires us to follow the naming requirements- https://i.imgur.com/eu10BTZ.png